# How to convert JSON to GeoJSON with Python

Tags: python, json, geojson

I'm actually learning how to do some cartography with python but first I would like to convert my json file to a GeoJson dynamically with Python. This is how my Json looks like :

```
[
  {
    "shape_name": "unit_shape",
    "source_name": "7724C_BUSSY_SAINT_GEORGES_Bussycomore",
    "building_id": "7724C",
    "chaud_froid": "Chaud",
    "geojson": {
      "type": "LineString",
      "properties": {
        "densite_cc": null
      },
      "coordinates": [
        [
          2.726142,
          48.834359
        ],
        [
          2.726149,
          48.834367
        ],
        [
          2.726202,
          48.834422
        ],
        [
          2.726262,
          48.834429
        ],
        [
          2.726307,
          48.834434
        ],
        [
          2.726316,
          48.834435
        ]
      ]
    },
    "to_drop": null,
    "id_enquete": null,
    "shape_nom": null
  },
...(many other features similar to the precedent one)]
```

Can someone please help me ?

Comment: What’s a `GeoJson` ?

Comment: GeoJSON is described at geojson.org. It's just a somewhat standardized way of storing geographic data as JSON; there's nothing very exotic about it. So the question for the OP becomes: What have you tried? What problems did you encounter? What exactly do you need help with? Please read ["How do I ask a good question"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Okay I reformulate my question. The problem here is that my file is written as a simple JSON containing geographical data (coordinates), this kind of files can't be read by GIS and can't be used with geographical libraries like Leaflet or Folium. So, my question is, how to rewrite it (reformat the syntaxe) as plain GeoJSON with Python.

Comment: You do that by writing a small program, probably using Python's `json` module, that reads the input file, makes the necessary adjustments, and writes the output file. If you run into problems with that, you are welcome to ask *specific* questions about those problems. Right now, this question reads like "please write my code for me".

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I'm actually a beginner in python so I didn't know that a module named json was available. My code is now done, and here it is in case another stacker encounters the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
import json 

input_file=json.load(open("./data/data.json", "r", encoding="utf-8"))

geojs={
     "type": "FeatureCollection",
     "features":[
           {
                "type":"Feature",
                "geometry": {
                "type":"LineString",
                "coordinates":d["geojson"]["coordinates"],
            },
                "properties":d,
        
         } for d in input_file 
    ]  
 }

output_file=open("./data/geodata.json", "w", encoding="utf-8")
json.dump(geojs, output_file)


output_file.close()
```